# Proof of the inequality $\frac{y}{x}-1-\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-y)^2}{x}$ when $x,y \in (0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$\frac{y}{x}-1-\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-y)^2}{x} \quad \forall x,y \in (0,1]$$

The statement looks simple enough that it may have a simple proof. However, I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\p\partial$Let $d(x,y)$ denote the difference between the left- and right-hand sides of the inequality in question. We want to show that $d(x,y)\ge0$ for $x$ and $y$ in $(0,1]$.

For such $x$ and $y$, we have $xy\,\p_y d(x,y)=(x-y)(y-1)$ and $d(x,0+)=\infty$. So, without loss of generality (wlog), either $y=x$ (and then the inequality $d(x,y)\ge0$ is trivial) or $y=1$. Next, $2x^2\,\p_x d(x,1)=-(1-x)^2\le0$ for $x\in(0,1]$. So, wlog $x=1=y$, and then the inequality $d(x,y)\ge0$ is trivial. $\quad\Box$

Answer (score 6):

For fixed $y/x$, LHS is fixed and RHS is maximal when $\max(x, y) =1$. So, it suffices to prove the inequality for $x=1$ and for $y=1$.

If $x=1$, denote $y=1-t$, the inequality reads as $-t-\log(1-t)\ge t^2/2$ that follows from the expansion $-\log(1-t)=\sum t^k/k$.

If $y=1$, denote $1/x=t+1$, the inequality reads as $t-\log(1+t)\ge \frac {t^2}{2(t+1)}$, or $f(t) :=t-\frac {t^2}{2(t+1)}-\log(1+t)\ge 0$. We have $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\frac{t^2}{2(1+t)^2}\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed $x\in (0, 1]$, let
$$f(y) := \frac{y}{x} - 1 - \ln\frac{y}{x} - \frac12\frac{(x-y)^2}{x}.$$

We have
$$f'(y) = \frac{(1 - y)(y - x)}{xy}.$$

If $x\in (0, 1)$, we have $f'(y) \le 0$ on $(0, x)$,
and $f'(y) \ge 0$ on $(x, 1]$.
Thus, $f(y) \ge f(x) =  0$ for all $y\in (0, 1]$.

If $x = 1$, we have $f'(y) = - \frac{(1-y)^2}{y} \le 0$ on $(0, 1]$.
Thus, $f(y) \ge f(1) = 0$ for all $y\in (0, 1]$.

We are done.